# Advanced query in Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two sort of tables. The first sort has a `TBL$` prefix and the second a `LOG$` prefix.
If there is a `LOG$TABLE_NAME` table than there is also a `TBL$TABLE_NAME` table. Because `LOG$` tables are generated from `TBL$` tables. The problem is when I want to search all user tables from oracles `USER_TABLES` table. I want to search by name only the `TBL$` tables with 2 parameters. First is the name, and the second is a String ('YES' or 'NO) who indicates if the searched table has a corresponding `LOG$` table. Without this second parameter, my query looks so:

```
SELECT ut.table_name AS id,
       utc.comments  AS comments
  FROM user_tables ut
  LEFT JOIN user_tab_comments utc
    ON ut.table_name = utc.table_name
 WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(ut.table_name), 1, 4) = 'TBL$'
   AND TRIM(UPPER(ut.table_name)) LIKE TRIM(UPPER('%'|| :table_name ||'%'))
```

So, if you could help me to itegrate this second parameter into the query it would be great.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with the query?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a left-outer self-join and check for existence:

```
SELECT
  ut.table_name AS id
, CASE WHEN ut_log.table_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END has_log
FROM user_tables ut
LEFT JOIN user_tables ut_log ON ut_log.table_name = replace(ut.table_name, 'TBL$', 'LOG$')
WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(ut.table_name), 1, 4) = 'TBL$'
```